# Codeception cleanup vs. depends

Tags: php, testing, codeception

When working with Codeception Acceptance tests i got to realise the best way is to cleanup the database before every test and make every test independent.

But some Cest Tests depend on each other. So if i write:

```
/**
 * @depends createObjectBase
 * @___skip     
 */   
 public function createObjectMore(AcceptanceTester $I)
 {
```

the data created in the DB from the `createObjectBase` test is gone because of the cleanup. But that data is needed for the `createObjectMore` test.

I cannot combine them into one test because in reality there are multiple areas with very different tests, so `createObjectMore` is just a placeholder here.

So whats the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Cests that depend on `createObjectBase` can extend an abstract (cest?) class that will have that method as protected, and then in child Cests use `@before createObjectbase` annotation to have it executed before each method which requires that data. Basically, you gotta do it every time because the data won't be persisted across tests.

Excerpt from the [docs](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#BeforeAfter-Annotations):

> You can control execution flow with @before and @after annotations.
>   You may move common actions into protected (non-test) methods and
>   invoke them before or after the test method by putting them into
>   annotations. It is possible to invoke several methods by using more
>   than one @before or @after annotation. Methods are invoked in order
>   from top to bottom.